# Apache mod_ssl log client certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, client-certificates

In my apache web-server there is a path where clients must authenticate with a valid certificate.

Sometimes there is a client (a soap - webservice) that can't connect, my apache return 403 "sslv3 alert bad certificate (SSL alert number 42) -- Subject CN in certificate not server name or identical to CA!?" and I need to check why and which certificate it is using.

I setup trace3 loglevel for mod_ssl and a customlog like this:

```
CustomLog /var/log/httpd-ssl.log "%t %h \"%{User-agent}i\" %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %>s \"%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}x\" <<<%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}x>>>"

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_engine.log
    LogLevel trace3
</IfModule>
```

In the first file log I can see all the informations of client that can connect but when the client fail there aren't the useful information:

```
[16/Feb/2019:11:01:43 +0100] XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX "IBM WebServices/1.0" - - "POST MYSECRETPATH HTTP/1.1" 403 "-" <<<->>>
```

In the second one I can see some information like:

```
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.288418 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(359): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 5 (server XXX.XXX.XXX:443)
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.288591 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(743): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] AH02255: Changed client verification type will force renegotiation
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.557866 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 99609] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] AH02221: Requesting connection re-negotiation
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.557902 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(970): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] AH02260: Performing full renegotiation: complete handshake protocol (client does support secure renegotiation)
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.557919 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1988): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.557932 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1996): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Loop: SSL renegotiate ciphers
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.557948 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1996): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write hello request A
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.557978 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1996): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 flush data
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.557986 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1996): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write hello request C
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.557996 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 99609] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] AH02226: Awaiting re-negotiation handshake
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.558005 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1988): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.558016 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1996): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Loop: before accept initialization
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.590106 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2141): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] AH02645: Server name not provided via TLS extension (using default/first virtual host)
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.590134 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1996): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 read client hello A
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.590146 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1996): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write server hello A
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.590177 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1996): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write certificate A
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.590190 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1996): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write certificate request A
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.590217 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1996): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 flush data
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.887495 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2001): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Read: SSLv3 read client certificate A
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.887530 2019] [ssl:trace3] [pid 99609] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2020): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] OpenSSL: Exit: failed in SSLv3 read client certificate A
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.887538 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 99609] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] AH02261: Re-negotiation handshake failed
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.887567 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 99609] SSL Library Error: error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate (SSL alert number 42) -- Subject CN in certificate not server name or identical to CA!?
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.887578 2019] [core:trace3] [pid 99609] request.c(117): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] auth phase 'check access (with Satisfy All)' gave status 403: /my/secret/path
[Thu Feb 21 13:57:55.887611 2019] [http:trace3] [pid 99609] http_filters.c(1003): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56892] Response sent with status 403
```

But there isn't something real useful.

**I want to log/write the certificate that apache is reading and not accepting. How can I log it ?**

Comment: If anyone like me came here googling "apache2 log client certificate" - the key part here is `"<<<%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}x>>>"`.
I was able to log client certificate using following config:
`LogFormat "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b %{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}x" ssl_extended
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd-ssl.log" ssl_extended`

Answer (score -1):

You can enable SSL debugging logs in your Application Server JVM config by adding the following JVM command line parameter and restart the Application Server:

-Djavax.net.debug=all

Depending on your WAS version, adding the above parameter is typically done by navigating to WAS Admin Console > Servers > Application Servers > YourServer > Process Management > Java Virtual Machine > Generic JVM arguments